# If list item is opened/hovered, the parent link has to have a different color

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hyperlink, hover

I want to create an effect, which is as follows: If I hover on my dropdown menu, the link is colored blue. Nice of course, but if I hover any list item in the dropdown menu, the blue link is going back to gray. How can I make the link stay blue, even if something else is hovered?

So this is the `normal` state. No hovers, no whatsoever. It is gray and that is fine. If I hover for example FAQ, then it will turn blue. That is ok too... But now. If I hover over FAQ, I will get a dropdown list. Then, if I hover over a list item, the FAQ message, which was blue, gets `GREY`. I want it to stay `BLUE`.

As said.. I want to get FAQ colored blue. I guess this has something to do with parent classes or active states? How can I do this? This is my code:

```
<div id="main-menu-wrap">
<ul id="menu-headmenu" class="menu-headmenu-container">
<li id="menu-item-429" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
<a href="blabla">
About us
<span class="sub"></span>
</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-435" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
<a href="blablbala">
faq
<span class="sub">blablabla</span>
</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-145" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
<a href="blablabla">
no
<span class="sub">hahaa</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-407" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor">
<a href="blablablabla">
blablbala
<span class="sub"></span>
</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-menu-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#menu-headmenu li .sub-menu {
    border-top: 15px solid #80806E;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.home #menu-headmenu li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    color: #1CBBED;
}
.home #menu-headmenu li li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
#menu-headmenu li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #80806E;
    color: white;
}
#menu-headmenu li li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
#menu-headmenu li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code, replace this rule:

```
#menu-headmenu li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #80806E;
    color: white;
}
```

with:

```
#menu-headmenu li a:hover, #menu-headmenu li:hover a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #80806E;
    color: white;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/ArKPL/)

Comment: Edit: yeah, something happened, but then again: now all list elements have the same color. I just want to give FAQ a different color.

Comment: @user1717526 let me understand... the first link must be blue on link AND submenu hover?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. FAQ has to blue when hovered and when a sub-menu item/menu is hovered.

Comment: @user1717526 ok, but there's no FAQ in your fiddle. Look at what happens to "About us". It works, so if it doesn't in your live code probably something else is happening...

Comment: Look at the image I gave: there is a FAQ. I see that ABOUT us works, it does too @my site, but, now all LINKS are the same color as ABOUT us. I just want it happen to FAQ, not to all links. So it works, but partially...

Comment: Alright, I have edited my code above. Now you can see no and faq.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of puttin the :hover on the link, put it on the list item. For example:

```
.home #menu-headmenu li:hover {...}
```

Comment: The hover on `a` element too is needed for `color: white;`

Comment: You are right. The a should be there, like in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

u can use this css code for handeling this issue:

```
.menu-item:hover a:first-child
{
    background: #80806E;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

best regards

Comment: Thanks, but that makes all list a items a different color. I just want to give FAQ a different color.